# JavaScript no iOS: Evitar eventos de clique ao dar scroll no iPhone/iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, eventos, rolamento

**Cenário:**

Tenho uma tabela e no Desktop devo manter clique duplo para acessar o conteúdo de cada item da tabela. Em dispositivos móveis como tablet e *smarthphone* o duplo clique não funciona e preciso implementar apenas um clique/toque.

**Código:**

Verifica se é um dispositivo móvel e mantém por default se não for o duplo clique. Se for um dispositivo móvel usa o evento de touchend para fazer o clique. O problema é que não está funcionando no *iPhone/iPad*, ao dar scroll ele já dispara o evento de *clique*. Funciona apenas em dispositivos Android.

Alguma sugestão?

```
var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var clickEvent = 'dblclick';

if(isMobile) {
    clickEvent = 'touchend click';
}

$(document).on(clickEvent, '.class', function() {

/* faz alguma coisa */

});
```

Comment: Testou apenas o `'click'` ao invés do `'touchend click';` ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sim, testei e não funcionou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu fiz um exemplo funcional no jsFiddle, também coloquei comentários que ajudam a compreender a lógica .
http://jsfiddle.net/M4gQG/1/

Lembrando que no desktop funciona com o duplo clique e em dispositivos mobile em geral, funciona com um toque, ele também permite rolagem  no touchscreen.

Comment: Esse exemplo está funcionando perfeitamente para minha necessidade Juan! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Implementar o touch com touchend é muito simplista, porque vc vai pegar casos como scroll e qualquer outro toque.

O melhor é usar alguma implementação do evento **tap**. Se usar Zepto, tem `on('tap',...)`. Ou usa o tappy (https://github.com/filamentgroup/tappy) ou HammerJS ou Fastclick ou ... etc.